# Google drive api access token taken for domain, can it be used for sub domain

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a site running on main domain. We have a google drive subscription module on which some users have subscribed. We are using google OAuth access. I have token stored in database for each subscribed users.
I have another site which is subdomain of the above one. I want to use the same token for google drive in sub domain. Is it possible ?